# How to get the http method used when calling an api in AWS

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have this lambda handler in my AWS. At the moment when i print context,
it does not display anything.
I really need to be able to determine the http method used at any point in time be it
GET,PUT,POST or DELETE

I will be calling various python functions based on the http method.

```
        def lambda_handler(event, context):
            eventJson = ast.literal_eval(str(event))
            print(eventJson)
            print(context)
            method_to_call = "Get"

            if method_to_call == "Get":
                  getUser(eventJson)
                  #putUser()
```

How can I get the http method used? I am testing from postman at the moment.

Comment: Http method information is existing in the event object.

Comment: Where does it exist and how do you get it? This answer is not helpful

Comment: `event['httpMethod']`